# Runtime error '1004' application defined or object defined error

Tags: vba

want to copy paste the values, correction required in below code or alternative required as i need to copy 3 columns from sheet east to sheet uniques (new to coding)

```
Sub uniques_sheet()

Dim unqrow As Long, lastrow As Long, i As Long

lastrow = Sheets("East").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrow
    If Sheets("East").Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
    Sheets("East").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2)).Copy
    Sheets("Uniques").Activate
    unqrow = Sheets("Uniques").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Sheets("Uniques").Range(Cells(unqrow, 1), Cells(unqrow, 2))
    Sheets("East").Activate
    End If
Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

Comment: You need to qualify the worksheet for the `Cells` calls; see the linked dupes.

Comment: how do i qualify worksheet for 'cells' ?, column 1 has categorical data

Comment: `With Sheets("East")`, `.Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 2)).Copy`, `End With`.

Comment: it is still not working, can you you suggest some other way to copy non blank data from first 3 columns of one sheet to another sheet